# Machine learning algorithm for finding most similar entries in dataset

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, learning

I have a pandas Dataframe, which has data as structured below.

```
    s.hp    s.attack    s.defense   s.speed s.special_attack    s.special_defense   p.name
0   39  52  43  65  60  50  charmander
1   40  45  40  56  35  35  pidgey
2   83  80  75  101 70  70  pidgeot
3   65  90  65  100 61  61  fearow
4   60  95  69  80  65  79  arbok
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
320 68  64  60  117 111 60  salazzle-totem
321 60  60  100 60  60  100 minior-violet-meteor
322 55  90  80  96  50  105 mimikyu-busted
323 55  90  80  96  50  105 mimikyu-totem-busted
324 75  110 125 85  100 105 kommo-o-totem
```

I'm looking for a simple machine learning algorithm or neural network structure. 
That can help me find the most similar pokemon, given a certain pokemon.

This would mean, that the `p.name` would be the label, and each of the other columns would be the features.

In essence, I would like to have the functionality so that I can find the most similar pokemon, based on a given name.

I have thought about PCA just to find similarities or use KNN. But I have not found an ML algorithm, that can allow me to predict on the same dataset.

Any suggestions?

Comment: forget the algorithm, you need the distance. most clustering algos would require the measure of similarity. you can always start with simple Euclidian or Mahnattan distance on the standardized features, of course, but this may not fit your needs.

Comment: @Aksakal Well in that case something like KNN would be suited right?

Comment: if you have distance, then KNN is one of simple ones to start with

Comment: But how can i use KNN, if i have so many different label types (each for one pokemon?). Can i have this many label types?

Comment: @baileyhaldwin You don't need to use the KNN model to actually predict anything, you just need to use it to find the K Nearest Neighbors. These are, according to your distance function, the most similar pokemon. It is easy to do this with the scikitlearn implementation in Python and I imagine it is also possible in R.